# Sequence $ x_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})\sin (n\pi/3)$lim sup, lim inf

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ x_n=(1-\frac{1}{n})\sin (\frac{n\pi}{3})$ for n $\ge $1. denote l=limit inferior and s=limite superior
Then

1. -$\sqrt{3}/2\le l\lt s \le \sqrt{3}/2$
2. -$1/2\le l\lt s \le 1/2$
3. $l=-1 $,$ s=1$
4. $l=0=s=0$

My attempt: I manually plotted the sequence terms for n=1,2,... for few n. And then saw that this sequence has 3 limit points namely -$\sqrt{3}/2$, 0 , $\sqrt{3}/2$. So least one is limit inf , largest of limit point is limit sup. 
But I need suggestions for more efficient way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you only *see* that the sequence has three limit points or did you actually *prove* that it is so?

**Hinit:** First, simplify the expression $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$. Then, it will be much easier to

1. Find the three subsequences converging to the three convergence points.
2. Show that these are the *only* three convergence points.

Comment: I only saw it, by plotting values of this sequence on paper

Comment: Plz give some himt on simplyfying sin term

Comment: @BigBang Calculate the term for $n=1,2,3,4,5$. Can you see a pattern?